# Magento products with stock and products without stock

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm building a Mawebshop with certain products that are always in stock. These products don't have a inventory qty.

There are also products that are not always in stock and these products always have x number of stock.

So I need to enable "Decrease Stock When Order is Placed" for the products which have a x number off inventory qty. But the products which are always on stock don't have an qty and need always to be visible.

I can't establish this with basic features of Magento. Does anyone know if there is an extension to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature already present with default magento admin panel. You just need to go under Manage Product and open any product. Then You need to click on inventory tab from the left tab section. There is first drop down Manage Stock which have two value YES and NO.

So you just need to select NO for those product for which you don't want the manage quantity and please select to YES for others.